# Can "desprenderse" be used to imply the English phrase "to give off"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

English: He "gives off" a strange vibe.
Español: Él se "desprende" extraño.

Comment: I disagree with @Efreen: yes, you can say: "Él desprende una sensación extraña" and "desprender" in this case means the same that "emana". "Desprender" does not always has to be voluntary, just like "emanar". You could also say "él desprende/emana un aroma extraño"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is closer to "give away"
In your example, give off, could be translated to "emana" o "genera"
English: He gives off a strange vibe. Español: Él emana/genera una extraña influencia/sensación
(note: added a suggested translation for vibe, although it is slang, so could be localized and have many options for translation)

You could think that "desprender" is a more conscious act, like "give away" that you chose when to do, while "give off" can happen any time.

"Desprender" is a verb indicating something is getting separated from something else, so it is technically correct, but not close to what the English phrase meant.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, in Honduras, Central America desprenderse is used to describe the action of a bag of garbage emitting a foul odour.

Comment: Yes, that same meaning is present in Mexico, but it's really not very common.

"That bag emits a foul smell!"

"Esa bolsa desprende un terrible olor!"

Answer (score 0):

Now, speaking of Mexico, **"desprender"** can be used in the following contexts, along with some of the already listed here, such emanate.

**1. Let go**

When somebody is truly attached to some other person (perhaps in such an emotional attachment state) - the word **desprender** comes to mean such as **letting go**.

"You should let go that relationship man...no good for you".

**"Deberías desprenderte de esa relación...no es buena para tí".**

**2. To remove**

This is a most figurative meaning, commonly used in a very specific situation...it tells to **remove** some *part* that has been attached into another *part*, **but either accidentally or likely "unwanted"...**

"I went through that yard and I got all covered by insects...I gotta get them off me!"

**"Pasé por ese baldío y me llené de insectos...necesito desprenderlos de mí!"**

---

- "Hey dude, come back...we forgot the camera...!"
- "Really? dude, the guy already tore my ticket...!"

---

- **"Hey! regresa...olvidamos la cámara...!**
- **"En serio? pero el encargado ya desprendió mi boleto...!**

---